# RC 2.7 Blender/Volumetric Shading Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I went onto blender.org and saw a Release Candidate for Blender 2.7 came out. In the description it seems the long awaited volumetric shading in cycles has been released. From what it sounds like is it allows you to make smoke and clouds in cycles. I tried the quick smoke and it has the same thing where the domain appears as a solid cube, and not invisible. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-------Update: 15.04.2014 (new link)

meanwhile it is possible:

HERE is an excellent tutorial explaining the smoke/fire setup in cycles in detail:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs

For the tutorial you'll have to download a current build from http://builder.blender.org/download/

The node setup is still quite complex but I asume there will be an extra node/shader for smoke making the setup much easier in coming blender releases.

Comment: By "the", I assume you mean the "Blender devs", are currently working on smoke rendering support? http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles

Comment: Yes, they work on smoke support and with the mentioned newest built you can already test it... the steps are: 1. go to the blenderbuilder website and get the newest blender version. 2 follow the tutorial step by step.

Answer (score 4):

Smoke rendering is still not quite possible in 2.7, simply because there is no way to put the smoke voxel data into a cycles shader.

This is a [target for 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap):

> For 2.71, the following features are planned to be worked on:
>
> - Volume rendering: smoke / voxel textures, better sampling, camera in volume

However, it is possible to render volumes based on textures:

[image]

Comment: In the release notes, it says smoke effects are possible, I just am not sure how. I have a picture of the 2.7 release notes on the post.

Comment: It's a little misleading. volume render has been added, which makes smoke rendering possible (but only if you can get the smoke voxel data). Rendering voxel data is a [target for 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap)

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. That makes more sense.

Comment: Smoke rendering is supported in GPU starting with version 2.77